# cambiar un caracter de una cadena que está en una estructura (struct)

Tags: c++, struct

estoy haciendo un programa en c++ que guarda nombre, apellido, dirección, barrio y ciudad por medio del uso de estructuras. Luego de que las almacene hay una opción que le permite al usuario cambiar una letra de todas las direcciones previamente almacenadas, para ello se le pide al usuario que digite la letra que desea cambiar y luego se le pide que ingrese un caracter o letra para que sea el reemplazo de la letra de las direcciones, por ejemplo; el usuario digita "b", entonces todas las letras "b" que se encuentren en las direcciones se deben cambiar por la nueva letra que haya digitado el usuario. El problema es que en la consola me arroja lo siguiente
"signal sigsegv segmentation fault".

Aquí el código que he escrito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct info{     //creación de la estructura

  string dir;
  string name;
  string lastN;
  string barrio;
  string city;

};

string dirRemp;   //cadena en donde almaceno la dirección 

struct info f[2];

for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{   
    cout << "Posicion persona: " << i << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese direccion" << endl;
    cin >> f[i].dir;
    dirRemp[i] = f[i].dir; //aquí guardo lo que llegue a
                           //f[i].dir para luego reemplazar
    cout << "Ingrese nombre" << endl;
    cin >> f[i].name;
    cout << "Ingrese apellido" << endl;
    cin >> f[i].lastN;
    cout << "Ingrese ciudad" << endl;
    cin >> f[i].city;
    cout << "Ingrese barrio" << endl;
    cin >> f[i].barrio; 
    cout << "\n";
}

short option;

do
{

    cout << "Bienvenido al directorio virtual" << endl;
    cout << 1. Reemplazar letra" << endl;
    cout << "Eliga una opcion" << endl;
    cin >> option;

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            short op;
            cout << "1. Reemplazar en la direccion" << endl;
            cout << "\n";

            if(op == 1)
            {
                string reemp;
                char remp1;
                string rem;

                cout << "Reemplazar en la direccion: " << endl;
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "Ingrese letra para reemplazo: " << endl;
                cin >> remp1;  //ingresa la letra de referencia
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "Ingrese caracter de remplazo: " << endl;
                cin >> rem;   //ingresa la letra para reemplazar la
                              //referencia

                cout << "\n";


                for (int i = 0; i < (int) dirRemp.length(); ++i) 
                {
                    //aquí se hace el reemplazo 
                    if(dirRemp[i] == remp1)
                    {

                        dirRemp.replace(i, 1, rem);


                        f[i].dir = dirRemp;


                        for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                        {                               
                            cout << f[i].dir << endl;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Opcion digitada no existe" << endl;
            return;         
    }

}while(option < 2);

int main(){

   ingresoDat();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿No tendria que ser `std::string dirRemp[2];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copie tu codigo en un IDE y me arojaba varios errorres, el Error de Segmentation Fault puede ser por que intentas escribir datos mas alla del espacio de memoria definido para una variable ademas llamas a una funcion que no ha sido definida y la mayor parte de tu codigo esta fuera del main. Editando tu codigo hice un programa que pide datos para llenar una estructura y despues muestra un menu de opciones, el programa se ejecuta de manera infinita hasta que selecciones la opcion de salir, mira el codigo que he escrito para que te des una idea de como lograr cambiar los caracteres de los campos en un struct.

La parte encargada de buscar y reemplazar las letras es este fragmento:

```
//Mientras existaun caracter del que estamos buscando en la string
    while (char_position != std::string::npos){
        char_position = informacion[0].dir.find(letra);
        //comprobamos si no alcanzo el final de la cadena
        if(char_position != std::string::npos){
            //Reemplazamos la letra que escribes en "letra" por "rem"
            informacion[0].dir.replace(char_position, 1, rem);
        }
    }
```

A continuacion el ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    struct info{     //creación de la estructura
      string dir;
      string name;
      string lastN;
      string barrio;
      string city;
    };

    struct info informacion[2];           //Dos estruturas de tipo informacion
    string letra;                         //letra a reemplazar
    string rem;                           //Letra que se va abuscar en la estructura para ser reemplezada
    int option;                           //opcion seleccionada del switch

    /* Este For pide que llenes los datos de 1 estructura que tienes declaradas arriba llamadas informacion
     * si quieres mas estructuras cambia el valor del limite del bucle for y
     * Tu la tenias como f[2] es lo mismo solo le cambie el nombre para facilitar de lectura aun que lo mas recomendable
     * seria que fueran creadas de manera dinamica con el operador new de acuerdo a la necesidad */
    for(int personaid = 0; personaid < 1; personaid++)
    {
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\t\tDatos Persona " << personaid + 1 << endl;
        cout << "Ingrese Direccion: ";
        //get line te permite escribir un string con espacios y se guarada los datos hasta que precionas enter
        // tu usas cin stream y si escrbias un espacio por eso te sucedia el error de segment fault
        getline(cin , informacion[personaid].dir);
        cout << "Nombre: ";
        getline(cin , informacion[personaid].name);
        cout << "Apellido: ";
        getline(cin , informacion[personaid].lastN);
        cout << "City :";
        getline(cin , informacion[personaid].city);
        cout << "Barrio: ";
        getline(cin , informacion[personaid].barrio);
    }

    do
    {
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Bienvenido al directorio virtual" << endl;
        cout << "\t1. Reemplazar letras" << endl;
        cout << "\t2. Salir" << endl;
        cout << "\t3. Ver Datos Guardados" << endl;
        cout << "Eliga una opcion: ";   cin >> option;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
        size_t char_position = 0;

        switch(option){
        case 1:
            cout << "Sustituir Letra: ";            //sustiruir letra A por la letra B ejemplo del ennunciado
            cin >> letra;                           //ingresa la letra de referencia para ser reemplazada
            cout << "Por la letra: ";
            cin >> rem;                             //ingresa la letra para reemplazar la referencia

            /*Este fragmento es el encargado de reemplazar las letras en las string de tu estructura. este ejemplo solo lo hace con
             * un campo de tu estructura en este caso (dir) usa tu logica y ordena el codigo en funciones para reutilizarlo y hacerlo
             * mas legible.
             * */

            //Mientras existaun caracter del que estamos buscando en la string
            while (char_position != std::string::npos){
                char_position = informacion[0].dir.find(letra);
                //comprobamos si no alcanzo el final de la cadena
                if(char_position != std::string::npos){
                    //Reemplazamos la letra que escribes en "letra" por "rem"
                    informacion[0].dir.replace(char_position, 1, rem);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Programa Terminado." << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            for(int personaid = 0; personaid < 1; personaid++)
            {
                cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
                cout << "\t\tDatos Persona " << personaid + 1 << endl;
                cout << "Direccion: " <<  informacion[personaid].dir << endl;
                cout << "Nombre: " <<  informacion[personaid].name << endl;
                cout << "Apellido: " <<  informacion[personaid].lastN<< endl;
                cout << "Ciudad: " <<  informacion[personaid].city<< endl;
                cout << "Barrio: " <<  informacion[personaid].barrio << endl;
                cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Opcion digitada no existe!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }while(option != 2);                    //Mientras la opcion sea diferente a Dos se sigue ejecutando el programa
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por su respuesta, fue muy útil, ya pude hacer que funcionara para que se reemplace en todas las direcciones de la estructura, sin embargo, soy un poco nuevo con c++ y no tengo muy claro el uso de 'size_t char_position = 0;'. Lo que entiendo es que se usa para iniciar la posición del caracter que luego se irá contando hasta que encuentre el que se haya solicitado, pero en realidad no sé si de verdad hace eso.

Comment: El tipo size_t representa bytes, la funcion find devuelve el indice 'la posision' del caracter buscado en un string 'array de carcateres' pero si no encuentra el caracter y alcanza el fin de la cadena devuelve un valor especial (std::string::npos) para indicar eso. Cada vez que llamo a la funcion find guardo la respuesta en char_position para compararla despues con npos si es igual npos significa que ya recorrio toda la string.

Answer (score 0):

Parece un error muy básico
 Yo creo que es esto:

```
dirRemp[i] = f[i].dir;

dirRemp es un cadena,

dirRemp[i] es un caracter

f[i].dir es una cadena
```

asignar un puntero a cadena a un carácter probablemente te lleve a `segmentation fault`, vamos que estas accediendo a posiciones de memoria inválidas.
El compilador tal vez entienda que `dirRemp[i]` es una cadena y use el valor (que puede ser cualquier cosa) como un puntero.